# When you compare an object to a reference object, what noun to use to refer to the former?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, academia, research

I am in the process of writing a research paper that compares my Methods A and B against a commonly accepted gold standard (reference) method. All methods produce objects that are identical in the ideal case.

I am now in the search for a noun to refer to the objects which are **not** the reference objects, i.e. objects produced by A and B, in the context of the comparison. Example sentence:

*The ______ are smaller compared to the reference objects*.

So far I have tried working with **test objects** and **input objects** and **sample**, but they appear wrong to my intuition. Ideally it would be a term familiar to other academics.

Comment: Why not just *The **outputs** are smaller compared to the reference objects*? Or rephrase so you can incorporate a verb: *Methods A and B **generate objects** [which are] smaller **than** the reference objects.*

Comment: Things produced (and we broaden language so that 'produced by method A' say is fine) are _products_. Perhaps this doesn't work well if 'objects' is broadened from 'material things'.

Comment: Along the lines of the comment by @FumbleFingers, how about *A’s and B’s **outputs** are small**er than** the **corresponding** reference objects*?

Comment: It's slightly "unusual" that the *reference* standard here is in fact a model itself, so we can't really refer to it as [***ground truth***](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/32514/ground-truth). In many similar contexts, we say things like *The **model** predicts objects which are smaller than the ground truth ones*. That's to say, ***model*** and ***ground truth*** are contrasted often enough that English naturally provides for easy referencing. But *[untrusted] **model under development*** and *[trusted] **existing model*** aren't really in the same league for "things that need names".

Comment: Familiar to other academics regardless of their field??

Comment: "Smaller than", not "Smaller compared to".

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes simplest is best. I don't see what's wrong with "The objects produced by Methods A and B are smaller than the reference objects." (Or FumbleFingers' suggested reordering.) It's a bit of a mouthful; you couldn't, say, label a chart with it. So you could also invent a shortened phrase and explain it: "The objects produced by Methods A and B (hereafter 'A objects' and 'B objects' are smaller...."

Note, you seem to have a need to include the word "object" (perhaps you're using "object" here for simplicity when the real work would use something else?). But if not, a simpler form of "The objects produced by Method A" is "the output of Method A" (or outcome, or product, or other suggestions that have been given).

Answer (score -1):

A  term found in this context, but perhaps not too usual, is the word "*individual*"; it is used commonly enough in biology. This term is used in set theory and logic; the entities discussed in this field are of a nature akin to those in the present context (in view of their abstractness).

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_discourse#See_also)): "For example, in an interpretation of first-order logic, the domain of discourse is the set of individuals over which the quantifiers range".

> (SOED) **individual**    **B** *n*. **1** A single thing or a group of things regarded as a unit; a single member of a class or group. **b** A thing which is determined by properties peculiar to itself and cannot be subdivided into others of the same kind. **c** *Biol.* An organism  regarded as having a separate existence; a single member of a species or of a colonial or compound organism. Late 18th century.